# Fluid Typography & Clamping Text Difficulties

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to place two headings side by side while making both headings fluid and responsive utilizing the clamp method. I was under the impression I understood how to apply clamp however after applying the clamp method to my headings neither grows or shrinks with minimizing or maximizing the viewport width. Can someone help me understand how to utilize clamp with my text headings?

```html
<header class="gohd">
  <h1 id="gfhd"><b>Sample Text</b></h1>
  <h2 id="gdsbhd">Research Guides</h2>
</header>
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: istok-web;
  font-style: normal;
}
.gohd {
}
#gfhd {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: clamp(1.5rem, 5vw, 6rem);
}
#gdsbhd {
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: clamp(1rem, 5vw, 3rem);
}
```

Comment: Your code works for me (Edge and then resizing the viewport).

Comment: Exactly. I completed my homepage utilizing clamp without a problem. Within my programming platform Dreamweaver, I can visually see the clamp function taking effect however previewing said code in Safari is a different case. Visually clamp is not taking effect. I'm bewildered.

Comment: What system/OS are you on when using Safari? And what do you mean by 'previewing' as opposed to 'viewing'?

Comment: Apologies if I use the incorrect vernacular. I'm referring to "viewing" my code to see what it looks like in the browser. I'm using macOS Big Sur. Is there a different way to achieve fluid text besides media queries?